# Turn off HikariCP in Play

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework, eclipselink, hikaricp

Since we are having our own db connections via eclipselink ORM (has its own connection pool), I am trying to turn off the jdbc connections and HikariCP completely. However, when I try to turn off these models by using:

```
disabled += "jdbc"
disabled += "javaJdbc"
disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
disabled += "play.api.db.HikariCPModule"
```

Play does not work anymore:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.ConnectionPool was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.ConnectionPool
    for parameter 0 at play.db.DefaultConnectionPool.<init>(DefaultConnectionPool.java:24)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:34):
Binding(interface play.db.ConnectionPool to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.DefaultConnectionPool)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2) No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound.
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 0 at play.db.DefaultDBApi.<init>(DefaultDBApi.java:27)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:35):
Binding(interface play.db.DBApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.DefaultDBApi)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
```

I am not sure if I understand why Play even provides jdbc modules and a connection pool and it seems that I can not turn it off and only use the remaining components of Play. Using EclipseLink with HikariCP seems to work (I do not know if it is actually used or just running at the same time), but how would I do it if I wanted, say, use C3P0 with EclipseLink?